# Excluding duplicate Gradle transitive dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle, build-dependencies

My project has the following dependency tree:

```
+---+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3
\--- io.pivotal:arca:1.0-beta.3
     +--- io.pivotal:arca-core:1.0-beta.3
     |    +--- io.pivotal:arca-service:1.0-beta.3
     |    |    +--- io.pivotal:arca-threading:1.0-beta.3
     |    |    \--- io.pivotal:arca-utils:1.0-beta.3
     |    +--- io.pivotal:arca-threading:1.0-beta.3
     |    +--- io.pivotal:arca-provider:1.0-beta.3
     |    |    \--- io.pivotal:arca-utils:1.0-beta.3
     |    +--- io.pivotal:arca-utils:1.0-beta.3
     |    \--- io.pivotal:arca-broadcaster:1.0-beta.3
     \--- io.pivotal:arca-app:1.0-beta.3
          +--- io.pivotal:arca-monitor:1.0-beta.3
          |    \--- io.pivotal:arca-dispatcher:1.0-beta.3
          |         \--- io.pivotal:arca-broadcaster:1.0-beta.3
          +--- io.pivotal:arca-adapters:1.0-beta.3
          +--- io.pivotal:arca-fragments:1.0-beta.3
          |    +--- io.pivotal:arca-monitor:1.0-beta.3 (*)
          |    \--- io.pivotal:arca-dispatcher:1.0-beta.3 (*)
          \--- io.pivotal:arca-dispatcher:1.0-beta.3 (*)
```

Note the leaves marked with an `*`, as they are the duplicated ones; how do I resolve these duplications?

Comment: The should be resolved automatically. They are not?

Comment: It is but whenever experience things like, for example, when I'm debugging and <kbd >Control</kbd>+<kbd>Clicking</kbd> a class to go to it, it'll suggest me two possible places. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's still the same class - exactly the same jar file. There's no difference which class will you pick.

Comment: So you're saying that build system wise, there's no duplication going on? Is there any way to exclude them?

Comment: You mean that e.g. two jar files will be included in final artifact? They will not. There's no conflict here.

Comment: You're welcome. If there are conflicting versions you will which one is picked, it will be marked with `->`.